# Homological dimension of completed path algebras.

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, quivers, homological-dimension

Let A = c[Q]/I  be a finite dimensional quotient of a path algebra over a quiver Q, with I being the ideal of relations.

Is it true that the I-adic completion of A has finite homological dimension?

Comment: Do you really mean the $I$-adic completion of $A$, or do you mean the $I$-adic completion of $c[Q]$?  (The ideal $I$ "becomes zero" in the factor algebra $A$.)

Comment: To continue Manny's question, another thing you might mean is: the completion of A with respect to the ideal of all arrows.  That is the completion which I have seen used (e.g., in representations of quivers with potential).

Comment: You're right: I meant the I-adic completion of c[Q].